# Swift Pusher example doing nothing

Tags: swift, pusher

I am using the starter code Pusher provides, when I put it into a basic swift project and I send it a message nothing happens. I have the cocoa pod package installed as well.

The statement "data received" should print.

There are also no errors.

[image: My code]
[image: the dashboard]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you initialising the Pusher object as a var? You need to maintain a strong reference to the object otherwise it can become deallocated.

As an example it should be something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var pusher: Pusher!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 let options = PusherClientOptions(
 host: .cluster("mycluster")
 )
 pusher = Pusher(
 key: "app_key",
 options: options
 )

// subscribe to channel and bind to event
let channel = pusher.subscribe("my-channel")

let _ = channel.bind(eventName: "my-event", callback: { (data: Any?) -> Void in
      if let data = data as? [String : AnyObject] {
          if let message = data["message"] as? String {
              print(message)
          }
      }
  })

pusher.connect()

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me as its not catching the event